# how to center text on an elevated button

Tags: android, flutter, button

I'm trying to center the text on an elevatedbutton but I'm not succeeding. Here's the code:

```
ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(                                  
                primary: Colors.blueAccent, // background
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  height: 2.8,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Add",
              ),
              onPressed: _addToDo,
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 2.8` from `style` and wrap `ElevatedButton` with `SizedBox` and give desire height.

```
SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.blueAccent, // background
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text("Add"),
        onPressed: _addToDo,
      ),
    );
```